# Better way to import multiple 'export' with ES6 or TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using D3.js V4 with the module and I would like to import few modules into a single3` namespace. The code snippet below is my current solution, is there a better way to do so?

```
const d3 = Object.assign(
  {},
  require('d3-axis'),
  require('d3-selection'),
  require('d3-format')
)
```

So whenever I need anything, I just call something like below

```
d3.format('.5s')
// OR
d3.select(something)
```

Is there a nicer way to import everything into a single `d3` namespace?

Comment: `require` is not ES2015. It's not any ES at all. The only ES import syntax is via `import`.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for the comment. I just updated the question is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> import multiple 'export' with ES6 or TypeScript

A typesafe way

```
import * as d3Axis from 'd3-axis';
import * as d3Selection from 'd3-selection';

export const d3 = {...d3Axis, ...d3Selection};
```

That said, `d3` was written before TypeScript and does not support type safety in its API decisions.

## More

Yes, you need to design for type safety, e.g. if your library uses direct array access it is inherently unsafe https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html

Comment: Thank you @basarat for all the advises above.

Comment: After reading the link you provided, I still do not quite understand things you talk about under **more** can you elaborate it a little bit?